# Bluetooth speakers and headsets, must be removed and paired every time

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headphones

Using Ubuntu 20.04, I easily add every kind of Bluetooth audio devices (headphones, headsets, and speakers) but every time I turn them off or I reboot Ubuntu, etc. they cannot be connected until I remove them, search for them and pair them again. Makes me even giving up using them at all.

Comment: do you have dual boot ?

Comment: nope, only 20.04

Comment: try the gnome shell extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1401/bluetooth-quick-connect/ BLUETOTH QUICK CONNECT, and see if it's working

Comment: it did not, shows the device (like ubuntu`s setting) but cannot reconnect

Comment: did you removed both devices and then pair from the beginning ? also try to update the system, there are some updates today for pulseaudio-module-bluetooth maybe this fixes the issue...

Comment: I have had my system updated about half an hour ago, and yes, removing the device and pairing it from the beginning works (and it did work before too), but I need to do that every time I use the device, and that is frustrating.

Comment: I try installing the package you mentioned from the beginning

Comment: sorry maybe I was not clear on the third comment..after installing the extension try to remove the paired devices and then repair again and see if it works...

Comment: I tried that, and the problem is still there. I need to remove and re-pair every time

Comment: I have this same issue.