# Can't connect to bluetooth speakers unless I remove it and pair anew

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 22.04

Just got my laptop back from repair, and re-installed 22.04 from scratch. Suddenly, I can't connect to bluetooth speakers unless I remove the device and pair anew *every time* I want to connect to the speaker. What gives? It seems to be this problem: [Bluetooth speakers and headsets, must be removed and paired every time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248764/bluetooth-speakers-and-headsets-must-be-removed-and-paired-every-time) but for 22.04.

Here's the log:

```
nov. 23 22:48:37 [my hostname] bluetoothd[759]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to [my hifi's mac]: Permission denied (13)
nov. 23 22:48:37 [my hostname] bluetoothd[759]: src/service.c:btd_service_connect() a2dp-source profile connect failed for [my hifi's mac]: Device or resource busy
nov. 23 22:48:43 [my hostname] bluetoothd[759]: profiles/audio/avdtp.c:avdtp_connect_cb() connect to [my hifi's mac]: Too many levels of symbolic links (40)
```